# Has a fully methylated pentagonal dodecahedrane been synthesized or at least attempted? If not, is there some reason it could not exist?

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis, stability

I first came across [dodecahedrane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dodecahedrane) in comments below [What dodecahedral molecule is Linus Pauling likely holding in this photograph? Does it have 40 carbon atoms?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/159395/16035)

Wikipedia's [Dodecahedrane; Derivatives; Hydrogen substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dodecahedrane#Hydrogen_substitution) says:

> Substitution of all 20 hydrogens by fluorine atoms yields the relatively unstable perfluorododecahedrane $\ce{C20F20}$, which was obtained in milligram quantities. Trace amounts of the analogous perchlorododecahedrane $\ce{C20Cl20}$ were obtained, among other partially chlorinated derivatives, by reacting $\ce{C20H20}$ dissolved in liquid chlorine under pressure at about 140°C and under intense light for five days. Complete replacement by heavier halogens seems increasingly difficult due to their larger size. Half or more of the hydrogen atoms can be substituted by hydroxyl groups to yield polyols, but the extreme compound $\ce{C20(OH)20}$ remained elusive as of 2006<sup>13</sup> Amino-dodecahedranes comparable to amantadine have been prepared, but were more toxic and with weaker antiviral effects.
>
> Annelated dodecahedrane structures have been proposed.
>
> <sup>13</sup>Fabian Wahl et al. (2006)[Towards Perfunctionalized Dodecahedranes—En Route to C20 Fullerene](https://chemistry-europe.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1002/chem.200501618) (also readable [here](https://vdocuments.mx/towards-perfunctionalized-dodecahedranesen-route-to-c20-fullerene.html?page=1))

The abstract of Wahl et al. (2006):

> “One-pot” substitution of the twenty hydrogen atoms in pentagonal dodecahedrane ($\ce{C20H20)}$ by OH, F, Cl, and Br atoms is explored. Electrophilic insertion of oxygen atoms with DMDO and TFMDO as oxidizing reagents ended, far off the desired $\ce{C20(OH)20}$, in complex polyol mixtures (up to $\ce{C20H10(OH)10}$ decols, a trace of $\ce{C20H(OH)19}$?). Perfluorination was successful in a NaF matrix but (nearly pure) $\ce{C20F20}$ could be secured only in very low yield. “Brute-force” photochlorination (heat, light, pressure, time) provided a mixture of hydrogen-free, barely soluble $\ce{C20Cl16}$ dienes in high yield and $\ce{C20Cl20}$ as a trace component. Upon electron-impact ionization of the $\ce{C20Cl16}$ material sequential loss of the chlorine atoms was the major fragmentation pathway furnishing, however, only minor amounts of chlorine-free $\ce{C20+}$ ions. “Brute-force” photobrominations delivered an extremely complex mixture of polybromides with $\ce{C20HBr13}$ trienes as the highest masses. The MS spectra exhibited exclusive loss of the Br substituents ending in rather intense singly, doubly, and triply charged $\ce{C20H_{4–0}^{+(2+)(3+)}}$ ions. The insoluble ∼$\ce{C20HBr13}$ fraction ($\ce{C20Br14}$ trienes as highest masses) obtained along a modified bromination protocol, ultimately allowed the neat mass selection of $\ce{C20−}$ ions. The $\ce{C20Cl16}$ dienes and $\ce{C20H_{0–3}Br_{14–12} tri-/tetraenes}$, in spite of their very high olefinic pyramidalization, proved resistant to oxygen and dimerization (polymerization) but added $\ce{CH2N2}$ smoothly. Dehalogenation of the respective cycloaddition products through electron-impact ionization resulted in $\ce{C22–24H_{4–8}^{+(2+)}}$ ions possibly constituting bis-/tris-/tetrakis-methano-$\ce{C20}$ fullerenes or partly hydrogenated $\ce{C22}$, $\ce{C23}$, and $\ce{C24}$ cages.

Neither Wikipedia nor Wahl et al. (2006) mention substitution of a  $\ce{CH3}$ group for each hydrogen, so I'd like to ask:

**Question:** Has a fully methylated dodecahedrane been synthesized or at least attempted? If not, is there some reason it could not exist?

Comment: companion question: [Has substitution of all 20 hydrogen atoms of pentagonal dodecahedrane ever succeeded?  If not, is there any reason that it can not be done?](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/q/163833/16035)

Comment: Option three - it could exist but would be pre-emptively difficult to make.